# No icons showing up (AstroNvim) - Linux

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, neovim

[image: Screenshot of Astronvim Homepage]

[image: Screenshot of Service File in Angular]

Hi I am new to Ubuntu and Neovim.

I installed Astronvim in a WSL Terminal in Windows. I am using Ubuntu 22 in WSL and Windows 10. I am also using TMUX. Before this I had a configuration of Kickstart nvim and I removed all the configuration files (I think so...) before I added Astronvim files.

I tried installing nerd fonts by downloading a single font and adding it to the `~/.fonts` folder and running the `fc-cache -fv` command. This did not work.

I tried downloading the whole nerd fonts package and using the `./install.sh` file to install and run the fonts.

Still the issue is not going away.

Any help or thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, so I had to change it in the terminal properties and it took affect. I installed the nerd font to windows and chose the font.

[image]

Edit : A better idea is to download Windows Terminal from the Windows store and use WSL through that, we still have to download and change to a nerd font though.